# How do I apply a transform to a variable in a snippet in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

With the code below I want to transform the variable in $2 to lowercase but I can't quite get it to work.

```
    "Build Model": {
        "prefix": "mod",
        "body": [
            "import '${1:../backend.dart}';",
            "",
            "class ${2:Class} extends ManagedObject<_$2> implements _$2 {}",
            "${2/(*)/${2:/downcase}/}",
            "${2:/downcase}" //would be nice to be able to do this
            "@Table(name: \"${2/(*)/${2:/downcase}/}\")",
            "class _$2 {",
            "@Column(primaryKey: true, autoincrement: true, indexed: true)",
            "int id;",
            "$3",
            "}",
            ""
        ],
        "description": "Build a data model"
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by changing it as following:

`"${2/([a-zA-Z]*)/${1:/downcase}/}",`

Here $1 refers to the variable within this expression (i.e. $2) and not the $1 variable higher up.

EDIT:
see answer below about using (.*) instead.

Comment: Technically the $1 in your transform refers to capture group #1 = `([a-zA-Z]*)`.  In your example that happens to be the entire $2 tabstop because of the way you wrote your regex (unless you might have digits in your $2 tabstop).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Mark. Do you have a recommendation on how to improve it? I'm a total noob when it comes to regex. Regarding your comment, I will never have digits in that tabstop, just uppercase and/or lowercase characters.

Comment: If you aren't worried about non-letters in your capture group then just `"${2/(.*)/${1:/downcase}/}",` is as simple as you can get.